# Lambda local run with sam detect environment and output logging

Tags: python, aws-lambda, aws-sam

I run a Python aws lambda locally with

```
sam local start-api -p 8080
```

And I use a logger with:

```
log.basicConfig()
log.getLogger().addHandler(log.StreamHandler(sys.stderr))
log.getLogger().setLevel(log.INFO)
```

But there seems to be no way to see the log-output on the console. Not with STDOUT and not with STDERR. So I thought about writing it to a file IF it runs in local environment.

Do you have an idea **how I can detect such a local run** during init phase? Or can you recommend a different way to see the log output?

By the way: is the logger output then globaly configured, also in sub-modules by the line above?

Comment: I meanwhile determined that outputing something to a file would not help as it does not run in the development folder but somewhere virtual - I think in Docker. So seeing the log output on sam local is still an issue I need to solve somehow.

Answer (score 2):

Ok I found the following things which may do what I need:

1. In sam local there is a environment variable **AWS_SAM_LOCAL**=true
2. You can not create a logfile but using the sam command to write to a file:

   sam local start-api -p 8080 -l app.log

So it is possible to use both to change behavior, e.g. in setting a different loglevel.